# How to install the latest version of g++

Tags: c++, gcc, g++

I'd like to know how can I install the latest version of g++ ( 4.8.2 ) on centos 6.5?
I'm having trouble updating to the new one. I'm currently on 4.4.7. Thanks in advance!

Comment: `sudo apt-get update` `sudo apt-get install gcc-4.8-1` I think.. Not too sure but CentOS might be different.. Try looking at: http://linux-problem-solver.blogspot.ca/2013/12/installation-of-gcc-482-compilers-on.html

Comment: Not sure how linux works but I believe I need a repository to install this.

Comment: i think this will help you http://ask.xmodulo.com/upgrade-gcc-centos.html